# How to remove the first key of JSON file?

Tags: command-line, 16.04, text-processing, json

I have a very big 5 GB json file.  I am trying to remove the first key from the file.
Input:

```
{"url":"example.com","original_url":"http://example.com","text":"blah...blah"...}
```

I tried:

```
jq 'del(.url)' file.json > out.josn
```

This command was working fine till I came across an error:

```
aims@aims:~$ jq 'del(.url)' file.json > out.json
parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 680284, column 49
```

Kindly, let me know the solution. What is the problem in `jq`?

Comment: Make sure the input is proper `json`, otherwise can't reproduce in `jq`-1.3

Answer (score 0):

Load json data as python dictionary and pop the specific key

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import json,sys

with open(sys.argv[1]) as f: 
    for line in f:
        data=json.loads(line)
        data.pop('url')
        json.dump(data,sys.stdout)
        print("")
```

Test:

```
$ cat input.txt                                                                                                          
{"url":"example.com","text":"blah...blah"}
{"url":"anotherexample.com","text":"blah...blah"}
$ ./pop_json_item.py input.txt                                                                                           
{"text": "blah...blah"}
{"text": "blah...blah"}
```

Comment: let me correct the question input

Comment: @JafferWilson OK, but for this script, it's irrelevant. We're operating only on one single key

Comment: Yes. I tried make it like that. also have tried `python` as per your suggestion. See:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42110561/what-is-the-issue-with-python-while-processing-my-json-file?noredirect=1#comment71389945_42110561 But I failed somewhere :P

Comment: @JafferWilson the problem is that you're reading file as one big dictionary. But your file actually is several dictionaries per line.   See this guy's answer to your question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42110822/3701431   He's doing the same thing that I do - reading each line as separate dictionary.